# .htaccess RewriteCond if QUERY_STRING is NOT matched

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Simple question to explain, with not simple solution to find for me.

I'm trying to trig a RewriteRule only if a certain QUERY_STRING is NOT matched.
Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !mystring
```

Obviously this doesn't work, how can I express the NOT condition?

***new informations***

Substantially, I have a rule that forces HTTPS for all HTTP request, but I want some request to be forced back to HTTP (due to external not-https content) so that IE doesn't show the "not-https content" error.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)/my_page.php http://my_website.com/$1/mypage.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !my_string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my_site.com/$1 [R]
```

The "!my_string" line represents what I'm trying to achieve, that is "force back to https" avoiding for a certain page (repesented by "my_string")

Comment: You are on the right track. Please show your whole rule (RewriteCond and RewriteRule lines) as well as provide URL examples (from => to).

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !my_string` is working fine -- tested on my Apache box with no issues (working as advertised). Most likely it is some other condition .. or whole combination of rules.

Comment: How much control do you have over your Apache? If you can edit server config or virtual host -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`), restart Apache, try problematic URL and check rewrite log -- you should see exactly what is going on (just try very simple URL and not real page with images etc -- the rewrite log can become HUGE within few seconds if you ave a lot of rewrite rules and many requests -- make experiment as clean as possible).

Comment: As I hadn't the control of the server needed to bring RewriteLogLevel to 9, I am not able to check this thing out... May hvae something to do with some rewrite_module setting?

Comment: I suggest installing some local Apache (on your PC -- WAMP,XAMP etc or in virtual one -- linux one) and test there -- this will be the best choice for debugging of such situations -- you will be able to see exactly where the rule fails.